# Target-specific recursive variable preprending

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know how to prepend a recursive variable without loosing its recursive characteristic at the top level of a Makefile. But I don't know how to do that when giving a target specific value. In code form

```
ALT1=a1
ALT2=a2
ALT3=a3
ALT4=a4
ALT5=a5

VAR=$(ALT1)
$(eval VAR=$$(ALT2) $(value VAR))

ALT1=b1
ALT2=b2
ALT3=b3
ALT4=b4
ALT5=b5

top: sub1
    @echo 'In top VAR is $(flavor VAR)=$(value VAR)=$(VAR)'

sub1: VAR:=$$(ALT3) $$(VAR)
sub1: sub2
    @echo 'In sub1 VAR is $(flavor VAR)=$(value VAR)=$(VAR)'

sub2: VAR:=$(ALT4) $(VAR)
sub2:
    @echo 'In sub2 VAR is $(flavor VAR)=$(value VAR)=$(VAR)'

VAR+= $(ALT5)
ALT1=c1
ALT2=c2
ALT3=c3
ALT4=c4
ALT5=c5
```

displays

```
In sub2 VAR is simple=b4 b2 b1=b4 b2 b1
In sub1 VAR is simple=$(ALT3) $(VAR)=$(ALT3) $(VAR)
In top VAR is recursive=$(ALT2) $(ALT1)=c2 c1 c5
```

while I'd like

```
In sub2 VAR is recursive=$(ALT4) $(ALT3) $(ALT2) $(ALT1)=c4 c3 c2 c1 c5
In sub1 VAR is recursive=$(ALT3) $(ALT2) $(ALT1)=c3 c2 c1 c5
In top VAR is recursive=$(ALT2) $(ALT1)=c2 c1 c5
```

Something which gives

```
In sub2 VAR is recursive=$(ALT4) $(ALT2) $(ALT1)=c4 c2 c1 c5
In sub1 VAR is recursive=$(ALT3) $(ALT2) $(ALT1)=c3 c2 c1 c5
In top VAR is recursive=$(ALT2) $(ALT1)=c2 c1 c5
```

would be acceptable but I'd prefer the previous output. I really need only the final expansion, the flavor and the un-expanded value are just an hint of how I think this should work.

Although a more widely applicable solution would be nice, I need only one which works with GNU Make.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only supported approach for such recursive variables is appending new values with `+=` operator. This is specially handled by make when dealing with recursive variables not to expand variable contents and not to complain about circular reference. You might want to use this approach, while reversing the actual generated values, which may also be defined once, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
ALT1=a1
ALT2=a2
ALT3=a3
ALT4=a4

VAR=$(ALT1)
$(eval VAR=$(value VAR) $$(ALT2))

define reverse
$(strip $(eval REVERSED=)$(foreach item,$(1),$(eval REVERSED=$(item) $(REVERSED)))$(REVERSED))
endef

VAR2 = $(call reverse,$(VAR))

ALT1=b1
ALT2=b2
ALT3=b3
ALT4=b4

top: sub1
        @echo 'In top VAR is $(flavor VAR)=$(value VAR)=$(VAR)'
        @echo 'In top VAR2 is $(flavor VAR2)=$(value VAR2)=$(VAR2)'

sub1: VAR += $(ALT3)
sub1: sub2
        @echo 'In sub1 VAR is $(flavor VAR)=$(value VAR)=$(VAR)'
        @echo 'In sub1 VAR2 is $(flavor VAR2)=$(value VAR2)=$(VAR2)'

sub2: VAR += $(ALT4)
sub2:
        @echo 'In sub2 VAR is $(flavor VAR)=$(value VAR)=$(VAR)'
        @echo 'In sub2 VAR2 is $(flavor VAR2)=$(value VAR2)=$(VAR2)'

ALT1=c1
ALT2=c2
ALT3=c3
ALT4=c4
```

Note defining `VAR2` which would reverse `VAR` when expanded. The idea is to add to `VAR`, but expand `VAR2` instead. Output:

```
$ make
In sub2 VAR is recursive=$(ALT4)=c1 c2 c3 c4
In sub2 VAR2 is recursive=$(call reverse,$(VAR))=c4 c3 c2 c1
In sub1 VAR is recursive=$(ALT3)=c1 c2 c3
In sub1 VAR2 is recursive=$(call reverse,$(VAR))=c3 c2 c1
In top VAR is recursive=$(ALT1) $(ALT2)=c1 c2
In top VAR2 is recursive=$(call reverse,$(VAR))=c2 c1
```

Edit: Removed unnecessary .SECONDEXPANSION

Comment: Interesting approach. I don't think the `.SECONDEXPANSION` is needed (at least I don't understand the purpose here and it works without in a simple example). Sadly if I want to prepend it is because appending is also used in constructing the final value and reversing doesn't help.

Comment: You are correct, this `.SECONDEXPANSION` was a leftover of some experiments.